# yocto: how to install command locale & localedef?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

How to install command locale & localedef for my image in the yocto project? I have try the following:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " glibc-locale"
```

But it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: In yocto it is sometimes difficult to distinguish between packages recipes and features and when to use them. Glibc-utils is a feature not a package. You could check your bitbake.conf, default-distrovars and local.conf.sample.extended to get idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`locale` is in a package called `glibc-utils` and `localedef` is in a package called `localedef`. Thus you can add these to your image by doing the following:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " glibc-utils localedef"
```

BTW I found these packages using the following command (there are other ways, but this will work if the package providing the file has already been built):

```
oe-pkgdata-util find-path "*/bin/locale*"
```

Comment: The problem is... there is NO package called 'glibc-utils' in any version of Yocto/OpenEmbedded. I tried jethro and up to the master branch. What layer is it supposed to be in?

Comment: `oe-pkgdata-util find-path "*/bin/locale*"` indeed finds /usr/bin/locale in package glibc-utils, but when I try to `bitbake glibc-utils` I get `ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'glibc-utils'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, found it. For me, the actual package was `libc6-utils`. Found it using `oe-pkgdata-util lookup-pkg glibc-utils`.

Comment: On my Yocto Zeus based distro it was "glibc-locale"