# Yocto install glibc-locale components

Tags: debian, locale, glibc, yocto

I need to install the glibc-locale package in my Yocto built Debian image. The final image should have the charmaps installed along with the "locale" and "localedef" commands so that "local -m" creates a list of available charmaps that is similar to that in an Ubuntu distro, and I can use localedef to create a custom locale and use that to set LANG.

I have tried these in the target image build file:

- IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " blah blah blah ... glibc-locale"

  - This results in a build error stating that: Package 'glibc-locale' has no installation candidate
- IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " ... glibc"

  - This does not install any of the necessary files although I can see that glibc-locale_do-package is run during the build process.

And these in local.conf:

- DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC_append = " libc-locales"
- DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " ${DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC}"
- GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES = "en_US.UTF-8"
- IMAGE_LINGUAS = "en-us"
- ENABLE_BINARY_LOCALE_GENERATION = "1"

I don't expect these to produce all of the desired output but I was hoping for something; I get nothing. I have also checked the variable values using "bitbake -e target" and according to the output, the above variables include the above settings when that image target is built.

I can run "bitbake glibc-locale" which successfully generates the desired output. I just can't do it within the context of a full image build.

I have also tried shoving the files I want, into the image using the output from the glibc-locale package and my own recipe. Doing this results in errors stating that multiple recipes are trying to populate sysroot with the same files.

I don't know what else to try. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735943/yocto-how-to-install-command-locale-localedef ? Have you checked that?

Comment: I did. That solution works to install the localedef binary and the glibc-util files but not the charmaps and other components that glibc-locale installs.